# Force Reload if no matching route is found in vue-router

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am struggling with a issue with vue-router.
I need to check a simple condition i.e.

`If no matching route is found. Do window.location.reload()`

I am using vue-router: 2.7.0 and vue is 2.4.2

I have gone through enormous blog post, but no where found a straight up answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll throw in the code and then explain.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.length === 0) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
  next();
});
```

router.beforeEach is called before a route is loaded with three parameters. `to, from and next`. Next being a callback function.
The key here is the matched property in the `to` parameter. It contains an array of matched routes. If not matched route is found, The length of the `to.matched` array becomes 0, which is the property I use to make the decision.

There should be an otherwise kind of property in the `vue-router`. But that's a fight I'll fight another day.